# Using a Parameter in Expression Transformation

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a workflow in which I've set up an expression transformation to select $$Param for a particular field, and then within the target properties I've set a delete value. I've tried this by substituting $$Param for a hardcoded value and it works fine, however, for some reason when I put in $$Param, it doesn't actually do the delete. Is there a reason? Am I doing something wrong?

Just for clarification, the workflow executes successfully - no error is thrown but it's not doing what it's supposed to.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you declare $Param as expression variable?

Answer (score 1):

$$Param needs to be passed thru a parameter file and you have the option to set an initial value when you declare the parameter in the mapping under Mappings > Parameter and Variables.

Have you looked at the session log to see what's the override value of $$Param is being used? If it's a SQL delete, try to turn see in the session log the query being executed in the database.

Comment: The issue was when I saved the parameter file in the concurrent settings area, it wasn't applied for some reason.